# How to get adCost from the new Google Analytics Data API (GA4)?

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

Written a script to export data from the Google Analytics Data API to MySQL. Works like a charm. Now I wanted to add adCost as a metric, but it doesn't show up in the list of metrics in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema). Also nothing like it (searched for things with 'spend' and 'cost'). In the old (Reporting) API it has always been available.

Doesn't Google offer this metric in the new API or is it just that it's not in the list. And if so, what would be the exact name for it?

Comment: The adCost metric is not available yet. I'll update here once the metric is available.

Comment: Thank you @Brett. Any idea when this will come available?

Comment: adCost may be available in the API in a month or two.

Comment: Is adCost already available @Brett?

Comment: adCost may be available in the Data API by the end of 2021.

Comment: @Brett Any updates on the "end of 2021" estimation, i.e. when we could expect adCost to appear?

Answer (score 0):

Google announced the update this week on 19-10-2022:

> On behalf of the Google Analytics team I would like to announce the following updates to the Google Analytics Data API:

**New Ads metrics added to the API Schema:**

- `advertiserAdClicks` Ads clicks. Total number of times users have clicked on an ad to reach the property.
- `advertiserAdCost` Ads cost. The total amount you paid for your ads.
- `advertiserAdCostPerClick` Ads cost per click. Ads cost per click is ad cost
- `advertiserAdCostPerConversion` Cost per conversion. Cost per conversion is ad cost divided by conversions.
- `advertiserAdImpressions` Ads impressions. The total number of impressions.
- `returnOnAdSpend` Return on ad spend. Return On Ad Spend (ROAS) is total revenue divided by advertiser ad cost.

https://groups.google.com/g/google-analytics-api-notify/c/rdmuC8IpBoQ/m/OSnFcLT9AQAJ

The new ads metrics are now also listed in the [GA4 API documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema#metrics).