# Is there a way to extract Ad Impressions, Clicks and Cost which were imported into GA4 via the API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

This was alsways possible in UA - why is such a basic feature not available in GA4?

Comment: Google announced the update this week: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66067084/how-to-get-adcost-from-the-new-google-analytics-data-api-ga4/74151418#74151418